# python - How remove all user installed python packages and or python itself in order to start again with a clean install?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pip, raspberry-pi3

While doing some python programming on raspberry pi running raspbian, I installed python 3.6 and subsequently many packages via apt-get, pip and I think from setup files too. All of it was done globally , but my understanding it is better and cleaner to install via pip in virtualenv.

Is there a more efficient way to clean up and reinstall all my packages outside of reimaging my raspberry pi and reinstalling python3.6?

Answer (score 0):

All user-installed packages go to `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` or `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`; Debian-based distributions also use `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`. Clear these directories and you're done. Perhaps you'd want to preserve `pip`-related packages — `pip`, `setuptools`, `requests`…